# Connection to specific WiFi if already have connection to another

Tags: java, android, wifi

I've been fighting like a fish for two days already, and I can not find a solution. I tried this code but it through time worked on Android 5(Lollipop) and didn't work at 7.1.1.(Nougat) I have another Scenario where phone loses connection and after this, it needs to return to the old Wifi.

```
public void setWifiConnection1(View view){
  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);


  WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

  wc.SSID = "\"NETWORK_NAME\"";
  wc.preSharedKey = "\"PASSWORD\"";
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    wc.priority = 999999;
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
    if (netId == -1) {
        netId = getExistingNetworkId(wc.SSID);
    }
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    wifiManager.reconnect(); 
}

 private int getExistingNetworkId(String SSID) {

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    List<WifiConfiguration> configuredNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    if (configuredNetworks != null) {
        for (WifiConfiguration existingConfig : configuredNetworks) {
            if (existingConfig.SSID.equals(SSID)) {
                return existingConfig.networkId;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

You can't execute your code right after this line. You should do a **wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()** check and subscribe to a broadcast if it's disabled.

Next...

```
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

This part is very odd: why do you disconnect ? Be aware that most of WifiManager operations are asynchronous so that's why you observe different results each time - real "disconnect" may occur after you've tried to enable your desired network.

You can always get inspiration from system API: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r30/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#2773

So correct sequence is:

```
wifiManager.addNetwork(...);
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

But if you are allowed to do so, it's more convenient to use system API directly.